# How would you pass HTTP Headers using a standard anchor tag?

Tags: html, rest, http-headers

According to [the HTML4 reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) there's no attribute to pass on HTTP headers using the anchor tag.

I would like to offer a link requesting for a specific file type using the `Accept` header.

The only way I can see is simply let it be, and pass a `GET` parameter.

You may as *why* I would want to do this... I intend to expose a bunch of methods as a public API, serving the results as `JSON`. And when doing requests using JavaScript, or another programming language, using the `Accept` header to request a specific response format is "The Right Way" to do it. But that would mean that I need to accommodate both the `Accept` header *and* the `GET` parameter in my code, which smells like a duplication of logic.

This topic is largely debatable, as such links may not be possible to bookmark in the browser... still... I'd like to know if it was possible without too much magic...

Comment: Using conneg is not always "the right way", it's just another tool in your toolbox.  Create distinct resources(URLs) for the variants and move on with life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see another way than using the GET parameter or an extension like

> http://myurl/page?format=json
>
> or better
>
> http://myurl/page.json

Which overrides the accept header (since the browser will only send it's default
accept header). Then you just need to initialize a format to accept header mapping like this (which I don't find duplicate logic at all):

```
{
    "json" : "application/json",
    "html" : "text/html"
}
```

Comment: If you use javascript you can make any request with any (accept) header and aren't limited to the 'default accept header'.

Comment: Yes but the OP was asking about standard HTML and the <a> tag. So either channel it through JavaScript or use en extension or format parameter.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid approach for allowing a user to select a specific variant.  There is nothing wrong with creating distinct resources/URIs to allow variant selection.  Server driven content negotiation is not always the right way.

Comment: Thanks. I really like the URL scheme `http://myurl/page.json`. I haven't thought of that one. @DarrelMiller: You are right that it's not always the "right way". But I am striving to not re-implement something that's already there. And, while the browser is rightfully sending an `Accept: text/html` header when browsing it would be useful to know of a "best practice" to override this header.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

> I intend to expose a bunch of methods as a public API, serving the results as `JSON`. And when doing requests using JavaScript, or another programming language, using the `Accept` header to request a specific response format is "The Right Way" to do it. But that would mean that I need to accommodate both the `Accept` header and the `GET` parameter in my code, which smells like a duplication of logic.

If I understand you correctly, you don't have to do this anyway.  Browsers already supply an `Accept` header.

Comment: Granted. But I was asking if it was possible to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like if your results are JSON, you will be sending / receiving from script anyway, which can provide any header you want.  Just have your link call a script function and you're done.

Comment: Using `JSON` was just an example. In my case I want to expose a listing which could be either accessible as `PDF`, `HTML` or `JSON`, where `PDF` would be accessible via a link.